# Show and Hide the content using a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to display a content `DIV` with a link of expand and collapse.

In my content `DIV` there is a unorder list. when the page is open I want to display only two list item with a expand link. If user need to view other list item they need to click on expand link. After expand the DIV link text must be change to `Collapse`. And also if in my unorder list have only 2 items then no need to display a link.

**NOTE:** unorder list is generating dynamically using `PHP`.

My HTML is something like this -

```
  <div id="mycontent">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="">+ View More</a><p>
  </div>
```

My Jquery -

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#mycontent").toggle();
});
```

This is my code so far - http://jsbin.com/mojuteve/1/edit

Can anybody tell me how can I do this?

Thank You.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just as a jsbin link.

Comment: That jQuery code doesn't look like what you posted at jsbin.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry... http://jsbin.com/mojuteve/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#mycontent li:gt(1)").hide(); // Initially show only first two items
    if ($("#mycontent li").length <= 2) {
        // Hide "View More" if there are no more to show
        $("#showmore").hide();
    }
    $("#showmore").click(function() {
        $("#mycontent li:hidden").slideDown();
        $("#showmore,#collapse").toggle();
        return false; // Prevent following the link
    });
    $("#collapse").click(function() {
        $("#mycontent li:gt(1)").slideUp();
        $("#showmore,#collapse").toggle();
        return false; // Prevent following the link
    });
});
```

Use the following HTML:

```
  <div id="mycontent">
    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>      
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    </ul>
    <p><a id="showmore" href="#">+ View More</a>
       <a id="collapse" href="#">- Collapse</a><p>
  </div>
```

And CSS:

```
#collapse {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Small mistake, `:gt(2)` should be `:gt(1)`.

Comment: Great.. @Barmar can we use another method to animate this instead of `slideUp` and `slidedown`. Reason is it is bumping element little.

Comment: Maybe use fadeIn? I don't really use these things very much myself.

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs for the links, and use DOM traversal functions to find the related content DIV instead of hard-coding `#content`. Please try to figure it out on your own, that's how you learn, not by me doing it for you.

Comment: Yes I have tried it using classes, This is what I tried -http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/BXDv8/1/

Comment: Wrong link, that's my fiddle

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use .closest() to this?

Comment: `$(this).closest(".content").find("li").gt(1)`

Comment: You're using `$(this)` outside an event handler or `.each()`, so it doesn't refer to one of the links.

Comment: Barmar, I am really not sure how to use it..very confusing it.. It greatly help me, if you explain it.

Comment: This is what jQuery is all about -- I suggest you review your jQuery textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn92C/2/

The code you should use, it will toggle the text within the "a"

```
$(function(){
    $(".mycontent").hide();
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".mycontent").slideToggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("more");
        if($("a").hasClass("more")) {
            $("a").text("- View Less");
        } else {
            $("a").text("+ View More");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it first has .find() but thats not needed here

Comment: that's damn confusing. How are we supposed to know where he was starting from if you change it? You should fork a new version, not overwrite his.

Comment: No I need to display 2 list items with the link to view more.

Comment: @TNK note that an id is unique in the code. Using 2 of them is not allowed, it actually will work but you can better use classes instead of id's

Comment: @TNK wathc the page on css-tricks.com: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: @Sake, I know the difference

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

CSS:

```
#mycontent {
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mycontent > ul {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
}
#mycontent > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px 10px 0;
}
#mycontent > ul > li + li + li {
    display: none;
}
#mycontent p {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#mycontent.visible ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
//Check if the list items are less than 3 and if so remove the more link
(function () {
    var listLenght = $('#mycontent ul li').length;
    if (listLenght < 3) {
        $('#mycontent a').remove(); 
    }
})();

//Variable for the text change
var linkText = ['+ View More', '- Collapse'];

$('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    // Better practice to toggle classes instead of using show/hide
    $('#mycontent').toggleClass('visible'); 
    //Text Change
    if($this.text() === linkText[0]){
        $this.text(linkText[1]);
    }else{
        $this.text(linkText[0]);
    }
})
```

But checking if the list length is 2 or less will be better to be done with php not js.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c5wWQ/)